# Rebuilt `super` partition won't boot

Tags: rom-flashing, android-11, ab-partition

I'm trying to customize an Android 11 super partition, removing certain apps. I used https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-ota-tools-lpunpack.4041843/ to unpack the `super` partition, mounted them as read-write using the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/Systemad/0dd94142e73c7338b3b369ba1a628f5a) and then repacked them as follows:

```
~/otatools/bin/lpmake \
--metadata-size 65536 \
--metadata-slots 2 \
--device super:2684354560 \
--group qti_dynamic_partitions:2680160256 \
--partition system:readonly:700383232:qti_dynamic_partitions \
--image system=./system.img \
--partition system_ext:readonly:300167168:qti_dynamic_partitions \
--image system_ext=./system_ext.img \
--partition product:readonly:68022272:qti_dynamic_partitions \
--image product=./product.img \
--partition vendor:readonly:304410624:qti_dynamic_partitions \
--image vendor=./vendor.img \
--output ./super.img
```

The command executes fine with the usual messages about invalid sparse images. But when I flash it using EDL mode, the phone won't boot. Furthermore, 7zip won't open this file like it opens the original `super` image, it detects it as a different format. It doesn't seem to be a boot verity issue. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Verified Boot and generation of vbmeta image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image)

Comment: @alecxs No it doesn't, I'm not asking about a vbmeta image and it doesn't look like a verified boot issue to me

Comment: @alecxs I think you're right that it's the dm-verity causing the problem. Unfortunately the bootloader cannot be unlocked on this device, and flashing the vbmeta without unlocking does cause the red warning screen.

Comment: try to hex patch `devinfo` partition https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4100897

Comment: I tried that already, but like the article says, it's only for zte phones. My devinfo partition is completely blank. If you look at the source in the Alephsecurity article, you will see that only certain bootloaders store the unlock info in devinfo - not mine, apparently. It looks like the bootloader itself is stored in the modem partition but I have no idea how to patch it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is bootloader state protected against physical tampering in Google Pixel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233301/how-is-bootloader-state-protected-against-physical-tampering-in-google-pixel)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `readonly` with `none`, and add the flag "--virtual-ab". That did it for me.